# Testing the result of HttpResponse.StatusCode

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I've written an `ErrorsController` that as you can imagine, has pretty simple methods to continue to serve dynamic content in the case of an error, e.g. 500.

Now what I want to do is test that in that method, `HttpResponseBase.StatusCode` is set to a given number while executing this method, but for some reason, the `StatusCode` property is always 0. This includes when examining the property directly after setting it.

**Controller**

```
public ViewResult NotFound()
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;

    const string PageTitle = "404 Page Not Found";
    var viewModel = this.GetViewModel(PageTitle);

    return this.View(viewModel);
}
```

*`GetViewModel` does nothing other than setting properties on a view model*

**Test**

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    this.httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    this.httpResponse = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();

    this.httpContext.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(this.httpResponse.Object);

    this.requestContext = new RequestContext(this.httpContext.Object, new RouteData());
    this.controller = new ErrorsController(this.contentRepository.Object);

    this.controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>(this.requestContext, this.controller);
    this.controllerContext.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext.Response).Returns(this.httpResponse.Object);
    this.controller.ControllerContext = this.controllerContext.Object;
}

[Test]
public void Should_ReturnCorrectStatusCode_ForNotFoundAction()
{
    this.controller.NotFound();
    this.httpResponse.VerifySet(x => x.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound); 
    Assert.AreEqual((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound, this.httpResponse.StatusCode); 
}
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: @NikolaiDante Could you elaborate? I'm only just starting to use testing

Comment: By calling a method on your manually instantiated controller, you're bypassing the entire HTTP stack. Your controller context, HTTP context and HTTP response are not used, you must check the `ViewResult` returned by the controller.

Comment: @CodeCaster That can't be true. Previously (before mocking the response/context). I'd get a null error in the method stating that `Response` is null. I can also see through debug that `Response` is my mocked object (very ready to be wrong about that)

Comment: @jumpingcode I stand corrected, you do connect the whole shebang in the `new Mock<ControllerContext>(this.requestContext, this.controller)`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Phew, I was panicking

Comment: Without seeing the fields, I had missed the `this.controllerContext` bit like @CodeCaster had. Deleted my answer. This is where [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add this in your setup phase:

```
httpResponse.SetupAllProperties();
```

This being said, you probably don't need those 2 assertions:

```
this.httpResponse.VerifySet(x => x.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound); 
Assert.AreEqual((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound, this.httpResponse.StatusCode);
```

The first should be more than enough for your unit test.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly

Comment: @NikolaiDante, no the test runner doesn't matter. You probably forgot to mock the HttpContext properly.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I didn't ask about the test runner :)

Comment: @jumpingcode, sorry, that was meant for  NikolaiDante :-)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov setting httpResponse.SetupAllProperties(); worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Tnx Dude! Spend hours on this

Answer (score 1):

I end up with an extension method for mocking HttpContext

```
public static class HttpContextExtensions
{
    public static void MockHttpContext(this Controller controller)
    {
        var httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var requestMock = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var responseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();

        responseMock.SetupAllProperties();
        requestMock.SetupAllProperties();

        httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(responseMock.Object);
        httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(requestMock.Object);

        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext();
        controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = httpContextMock.Object;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
someController.MockHttpContext()
```